# Problema para representar rankings con pandas.plotting.parallel_coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Estoy jugando con **pandas.plotting.parallel_coordinates**, intentando representar un "ranking" de posiciones... y me encuentro con varios problemas. Todos parten de esta dataframe:

```
+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--+
| ranking | Day 1 | Day 2 | Day 3 | Day 4 | Day 5 |  |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--+
| 1       | adria | adria | marta | marta | adria |  |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--+
| 2       | marta | marta | dani  | dani  | marta |  |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--+
| 3       | dani  | dani  | adria | adria | dani  |  |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--+
| 4       | abel  | abel  | abel  | abel  | abel  |  |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--+
| 5       |       | joan  | joan  |       |       |  |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--+
```

En resumen, hay varios jugadores, que suben y bajan en el ranking. Finalmente hay un jugador (*joan*) que solo juega dos dias, y desaparece.

Aquí el codigo que estoy usando:

```
plt.figure(figsize = (20,5)) # Plot Width & Height
pd.plotting.parallel_coordinates(
  df, 'ranking', # dataframe_name, column with variables = "Name"
  axvlines = False,
  marker='o', # Show marker
  markersize=12, #The Marker Size
  linewidth=6, # The Line Width
  alpha=0.9, # Opacity of lines
  )

plt.gca().invert_yaxis() # This inverts the Y aixs.
plt.legend('')
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight') # This is the style
plt.show()
```

El resultado es este:

[image: parallel_coordinates]

**Problema Nº 1:** Las líneas no siguen el orden de la tabla. Como podéis ver, *dani* no llega a estar nunca en primera posición, pero en la representación, veréis que sube dos posiciones en el ranking. Ocurre lo mismo con *adria*, que baja a la tercera posición en, y marta, sube a la primera. Pero esto no se refleja en el gráfico.

**Problema Nº 2**: No sé cómo representar a Joan. Su línea no debería existir hasta que no entre en el juego. Pero no me es posible representarlo de ningún modo.

En cambio, con otro set de datos, si que puedo hacer exactamente lo que quiero:

```
+------+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+
| Name | Day 1       | Day 2 | Day 3 | Day 4 | Day 5 | Day 6 | Day 7 | Day 8 | Day 9 | Day 10 | Day 11 |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+
| 0    | Bernhard    | 1     | 1     | 2     | 5     | 5     | 7     | 1     | 2     | 7      | 7      |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+
| 1    | Adrià       | 2     | 2     | 1     | 4     | 4     | 2     | 7     | 7     | 6      | 6      |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+
| 2    | Òscar       | 3     | 3     | 3     | 6     | 6     | 5     | 3     | 5     | 5      | 5      |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+
| 3    | Ariadna     | 4     | 5     | 6     | 2     | 2     | 4     | 5     | 3     | 4      | 4      |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+
| 4    | Mathieu     | 5     | 4     | 5     | 1     | 3     | 6     | 4     | 4     | 3      | 3      |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+
| 5    | Schrödinger | 6     | 6     | 4     | 3     | 1     | 1     | 5     | 6     | 2      | 2      |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+
| 6    | Joah        | NaN   | NaN   | NaN   | 7     | 7     | 3     | 2     | 1     | 1      | 1      |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+
Use Unicode symbols for table borders
```

Con este resultado:

[image: Parallel Coordinates 2]

En este segundo ejemplo todo funciona perfectamente:

- Las líneas se corresponden a la evolución del rakning
- El jugador*Joah* genera una línea en el momento que accede al juego, no antes.

Efectivamente, en el primer ejemplo, el ranking se compone a partir de la posición del nombre dentro la tabla, y en el segundo, se establece un número para definir la posición. Sé que son dos formas completamente distintas de trabajar. Pero me gustaria saber si hay algún modo de solucionar el caso del primer DataFrame... porque me he estrujado el cerebro y no logro encontrar solución alguna.

Aprovecho para comentar que esta es mi primera pregunta que hago en StackOverflow, y que estoy muy agradecido por todo el esfuerzo que hace toda la comunidad para dar respuestas.

Un saludo,

A.